# Probability that a symmetric random walk returns to $0$ exactly $k$ times in $2n$ steps

Tags: stochastic-processes, st.statistics, random-walks

I'm trying to find a formula to find the probability of exactly k returns in 2n steps of a symmetric random walk. More specifically, I am trying to show that the probability of 2 returns is exactly equal to the probability of return to 0 at 2n minus the probability of first return to 0 at 2n. I.e. probability of exactly two returns to 0 is $\ p _{0,0}^{2n}$ - $\ f _{2n}$   where $\ p _{0,0}^{2n}$ is the probability of return to 0 at 2n and  $\ f _{2n}$ is the probability of first return to 0 at 2n

Comment: Why do you want to show this?

Comment: Can't find a proof for it anywhere, just the formula

Answer (score 4):

Stated slightly differently, the formula says that
$$
P(R=2)=P(R\ge 2, X_{2n}=0), \quad\quad\quad\quad (1)
$$
with $R$ denoting the number of returns and $X_k$ denoting the position of the random walk.

For any path with $R\ge 2$, focus on the portion after the second return to $0$. We again start this final portion of the path at $0$, and thus there are as many paths ending at $0$ as there are paths that avoid $0$ altogether. (This is a well know fact about random walks; for example, see Lemma 2.3 in my notes [here.](https://math.ou.edu/%7Ecremling/teaching/lecturenotes/ln-rw.pdf)) If we count both types of paths in this way, we obtain (1).

More generally, the same argument shows that for any $k\ge 0$, we have $P(R=k)=P(R\ge k, X_{2n}=0)$.

Comment: Thanks for this. Do you know any literature that explains the first formula in detail as I like to read on it?

Comment: @Tarmmsh: No, sorry, I don't. But I was hoping my answer is actually giving all the details.

Comment: I cannot wrap my head around the >= 2 inequality